# want to show a specific data, but somehow the data are duplicate by something

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show a specific data with a specific quantity of the data using SQL. On this case, its should be shown only 5 records, but it shown 10 records and they are the same data, I really don't know where the problem is. any body can help to solve this?

I've just tried sort out the code, by running each of them, but I think i found the problem on the section #TEMPAD

[image]

anyone can confirm my problem?

```
--IMAGE : https://imgur.com/a/xgX5hub
DECLARE @Month AS INT = 1
DECLARE @Year AS INT = 2019
DECLARE @EmployeeID AS VARCHAR(16) = '01113'
DECLARE @BranchID AS VARCHAR(16) = ''
DECLARE @DepartmentID AS VARCHAR(16) = ''

SELECT * INTO #TEMPJAMINAN FROM(
    SELECT A.EmployeeID, SUM(B.Amount) AS JaminanPaid, SUM(A.Amount) AS TotalJaminan
    FROM Loan A
        INNER JOIN LoanDetail B ON A.LoanID = B.LoanID
    WHERE A.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND IsPaid = 1 AND LoanTypeID = '017'
    GROUP BY A.EmployeeID
)A

SELECT * INTO #TEMPKOPERASI FROM(
    SELECT A.EmployeeID, SUM(B.Amount) AS KoperasiPaid, A.Amount AS TotalKoperasi
    FROM Loan A
        INNER JOIN LoanDetail B ON A.LoanID = B.LoanID
    WHERE A.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND IsPaid = 1 AND LoanTypeID = '011' AND A.IsDeleted = 0 AND A.Paid = 1
    GROUP BY A.EmployeeID, A.Amount
)A

SELECT *, 2 AS SEQ INTO #TEMPAD FROM(
    SELECT A.EmployeeID, C.Name AS 'ADName', 'DEDUCTION' AS [Type], B.Amount
    FROM Salary A 
        INNER JOIN SalaryDeduction B ON A.SalaryID = B.SalaryID 
        INNER JOIN Deduction C ON B.DeductionID = C.DeductionID
    WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND A.Month = @Month AND A.Year = @Year
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.EmployeeID, C.Name AS 'ADName', 'ALLOWANCE' AS [Type], B.Amount
    FROM Salary A 
        INNER JOIN SalaryAllowance B ON A.SalaryID = B.SalaryID 
        INNER JOIN Allowance C ON B.AllowanceID = C.AllowanceID
    WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND A.Month = @Month AND A.Year = @Year
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.EmployeeID, E.Name AS 'ADName', 'DEDUCTION' AS [Type], SUM(F.Amount) AS Amount
    FROM Employee A
        INNER JOIN Branch B ON A.BranchID = B.BranchID
        INNER JOIN Department C ON A.DepartmentID = C.DepartmentID
        INNER JOIN Loan D ON A.EmployeeID = D.EmployeeID
        INNER JOIN LoanDetail F ON D.LoanID = F.LoanID AND (MONTH(F.TransDate) = @Month AND YEAR(F.TransDate) = @Year AND IsPaid = 1)
        INNER JOIN LoanType E ON D.LoanTypeID = E.LoanTypeID
    WHERE A.IsDeleted = 0 AND A.EndWorking IS NULL AND A.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
    GROUP BY A.EmployeeID, E.Name
)A

SELECT
    UPPER(C.Name) AS CompanyName,
    C.Address1 AS [Address1],
    C.Address2 AS [Address1],

    @Year AS [Year],
    UPPER(CAST(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,@Month,-1)) AS VARCHAR(20))) AS [Month],

    B.NIK AS NIKKaryawan,
    UPPER(B.Name) AS NamaKaryawan,

    UPPER(D.Name) AS Title,
    UPPER(E.Name) AS Department,

    A.HKS AS TotalHKS,
    A.HKA AS TotalHKA,
    B.AccountBank AS RekeningKaryawan,
    B.BankName AS BankKaryawan,

    F.JaminanPaid,
    F.TotalJaminan,

    G.KoperasiPaid,
    G.TotalKoperasi,

    A.Netto AS TotalGaji,

    VE.ADName,
    VE.Type,
    VE.Amount,
    2 AS SEQ
FROM Salary A
    INNER JOIN Employee B ON A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN Company C ON B.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
    INNER JOIN Title D ON B.TitleID = D.TitleID
    INNER JOIN Department E ON B.DepartmentID = E.DepartmentID
    LEFT JOIN #TEMPJAMINAN F ON A.EmployeeID = F.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN #TEMPKOPERASI G ON A.EmployeeID = G.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN #TEMPAD VE ON A.EmployeeID = VE.EmployeeID
WHERE A.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND A.IsDeleted = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    UPPER(C.Name) AS CompanyName,
    C.Address1 AS [Address1],
    C.Address2 AS [Address1],

    @Year AS [Year],
    UPPER(CAST(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,@Month,-1)) AS VARCHAR(20))) AS [Month],

    B.NIK AS NIKKaryawan,
    UPPER(B.Name) AS NamaKaryawan,

    UPPER(D.Name) AS Title,
    UPPER(E.Name) AS Department,

    A.HKS AS TotalHKS,
    A.HKA AS TotalHKA,
    B.AccountBank AS RekeningKaryawan,
    B.BankName AS BankKaryawan,

    F.JaminanPaid,
    F.TotalJaminan,

    G.KoperasiPaid,
    G.TotalKoperasi,

    A.Netto AS TotalGaji,

    'GAJI POKOK',
    'ALLOWANCE',
    B.BasicSalary,
    1 AS SEQ
FROM Salary A
    INNER JOIN Employee B ON A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN Company C ON B.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
    INNER JOIN Title D ON B.TitleID = D.TitleID
    INNER JOIN Department E ON B.DepartmentID = E.DepartmentID
    LEFT JOIN #TEMPJAMINAN F ON A.EmployeeID = F.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN #TEMPKOPERASI G ON A.EmployeeID = G.EmployeeID
WHERE A.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND A.IsDeleted = 0
AND (B.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID OR @DepartmentID = '')
AND (B.BranchID = @BranchID OR @BranchID = '')

GROUP BY


DROP TABLE #TEMPAD
DROP TABLE #TEMPJAMINAN
DROP TABLE #TEMPKOPERASI
```

I expect the output of 5 data instead of 10

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I'm using the standard sql server

Comment: Simplify your problem. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi have you try to use UNION instead off UNION ALL ?